# Extensão do google chrome não mostra popup padrão

Tags: html5, json, google, google-chrome-extensão

Comecei ontem a desenvolver extensões para o google chrome, e segui como manda o google:

Declarei meu manifesto e adicionei a página com a popup:

```
{
    "name": "ODM Integration",
    "description": "Open Download Manager integration for google chrome",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "default_locale": "en_US",
    "author": "Samuel Ives",

    "browser_action":{
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions":[
        "pageCapture"
    ]
}
```

Página html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>ODM Integration<title>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Files</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

porém o que ele retorna quando clico na extensão é um quadrado de uns 12 x 12 pixels em branco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro problema, para usar

```
 "default_locale": "en_US"
```

é necessário que exista a pasta `_locales`, já o segundo problema é que você não fechou a tag title:

```
 <title>ODM Integration<title>
```

O HTML está sendo gerado assim:

[image: erro no html]

Ou seja tudo esta sendo considerado texto, o correto seria:

```
 <title>ODM Integration</title>
```

HTML inteiro:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ODM Integration</title>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Files</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Realmente não tinha percebido a tag title não tinha feichado a tag title, isso se deve ao costume do sublime text automaticamente abrir e feichar tags, colchetes etc... , mas porém já tenho uma pasta chamada _locales e dentro tenho en_US e pt_BR ambos com messages.json. Apenas feichei a tag e funcionou perfeitamente.